# Prevent htaccess from affecting ajax file requests

Tags: ajax, .htaccess

I have some rewrite rules in my `.htaccess` file for clean URLs, and I also need AJAX calls in my web pages. I have problems with ajax file requests because of the rewrite rules. Here is my htaccess file content:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase /~mavili/loran/orders/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When I do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'http://domain.com/misc/page.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#load_content').html(data);
    },
    error: function() {
       $('#load_content').html('Error: Unable to load file.');
    }
});
```

the request for `http://domain.com/misc/page.php` goes through the htaccess rewrite rules and messes everything. Is there any way to prevent AJAX calls from going through htaccess settings?

Comment: Unfortunately not really.  AJAX calls are the same as any other web connection, just the way they are handled is treated differently.  You will need to revise your htaccess to ignore a specific folder or file in order to not interrupt the Ajax call.

Comment: .htaccess control your application and all the request goes through the .htaccess file rules. You have to think another way.

Comment: I'd suggest those who downvoted to read the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of making Ajax request skip the rules is sticking a dummy query parameter in the URL e.g. this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'http://domain.com/misc/page.php&skip=1',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#load_content').html(data);
    },
    error: function() {
       $('#load_content').html('Error: Unable to load file.');
    }
});
```

And have your rewrite rules like this to skip all requests with `?skip=1` query parameter:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^skip=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```