# How to redirect all urls within a directory to a hashed version of the same url?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Here's what I want to achieve.

A user clicks a link or types into the location bar something like `http://test.com/projects/a-project`

The page is redirected to `http://test.com/projects/#a-project`

There exist multiple projects within the projects sub-directory.

Here is my htaccess so far

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule /?projects/(.*)$ /projects/#$1 [L,R,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This works fine when testing on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/  but on my site causes a redirect loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop because hashtag is not seen by htaccess (it is client side only).
So your rule is executed again and again.

Instead, you can use this code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/projects/([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /projects/#%1 [R,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Note: `{THE_REQUEST}` is used to make sure the request is not coming from an internal redirect but from the original request (client request). So in this code, it redirects to `#` only if it comes from client request (and not after, which was causing an infinite loop).

---

EDIT: to solve your ajax problem

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/projects/([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ajax=true$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /projects/#%1 [R,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Ajax call: http://test.com/projects/a-project?ajax=true
Normal (user) call: http://test.com/projects/a-project (redirects to `#` equivalent)

Comment: Yes this works but it is messing up some ajax requests I'm making. Any ideas on how to prevent it rewriting for ajax? Also would you care to explain what you have done a little more?

Comment: I added a note to explain what is `{THE_REQUEST}`. For your ajax problem, you can avoid it by using some hacks. Are you using `POST` or `GET` with ajax ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm using GET.

Comment: Damn... There's another possibility: adding a GET parameter to ajax call part (for instance `ajax=true`) or even add an `/ajax/` part in url and modify a bit the rule above not to redirect in that case

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426583/prevent-htaccess-from-affecting-ajax-file-requests at the moment

Comment: Instead of explaining it in a comment, i edited my answer to be easier to understand